# Best practice for saving state on pause/exit of mobile app in Ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm wondering what the best solution is for saving state in cross-platform mobile applications that are using Ionic Framework.

I'm currently using a "GlobalService" provider with variables that i get from Firestore, such as:
- userRole (member/administrator/none)
- userOrganization (12345678)

The problem is that during development, or running the app on an actual device, all these variables are cleared on "app resume" or when recompiling during dev. And I'm using these variables a lot in different components.

I would like to avoid doing API calls to Firestore all the time to refresh this data. Could anyone explain to me how i should go about doing this?

I've tried ionic storage and putting this in my public variables, but still, this code would then have to be run in every "root" component on "app resume".

I'm thinking there has to be a way to save state in app.module.ts or similar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use cordova-sqlite-storage? It is integrated with ionic.  You can check here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage. It provides a simply get/set/remove by key, promise based API.

Storage creates a local storage that persists data - unless you clear it explcitly (for example when clearing "App Data").
It also works well in browsers when testing. You can find it undre Application -> Storage -> IndexedDb

Example usage:

```
import { Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class StateService{

constructor(private storage: Storage){
}
set<T>(key: string, data: T){
    this.storage.set(key, data)
    .then(() => {})
    .catch(() => {});
}

get<T>(key: string): Promise<T>{
    return this.storage.get(key)
    .then((data:T) => {
        return data;
    })
    .catch(() => null);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But even if using local storage, will i not have to get these variables in every component that is going to use it, every time?

Comment: You can have a global service that you want to have instant access. Each time you 'resume' the app you can make sure variables are set. You can use "platform" from "@ionic/platform" and add a subscription at app init  platform.resume.subscribe(...
Use it to update global service with store data